# How to correctly parse the JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

I have developed a Cordova android plugin for my library. The library is used for sending events across different connected devices.

JS interface receives a JSON from the java side. What I want to do is to parse this before reaching the application so that the developer can directly use it as a JS object. When I tried to parse the JSON in my plugin's JS interface, I am running into issues. Below is an example:

Received by JS interface:

```
{"key":"name","data":"{\"name\":\"neil\",\"age\":2,\"address\":\"2 Hill St\"}"}
```

After parsing in JS interface:

```
Object {key: "name", data: "{"name":"neil","age":2,"address":"2 Hill St"}"}
data:"{"name":"neil","age":2,"address":"2 Hill St"}"
key:"name"
__proto__:Object
```

As you can see, if this data reaches the app and the developer accesses the data:

```
eventData.key = name;
eventData.data = {"name":"neil","age":2,"address":"2 Hill St"};
eventData.data.name = undefined
```

How can I parse the inner data as well in my JS interface so that the developer can access directly. In the above case, he has to parse eventData.data to access the properties. I don't want this to happen and I want to do this in JS interface itself.

Please note that eventData can have many properties and hence they should be properly parsed before passing into the app.

I am new to Javascript and hence finding it difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: `eventData.data = JSON.parse(eventData.data)`

Comment: Received by JS interface it looks to me that it is receiving a JSON object but the data property contains a string to be parsed

Comment: `Received by JS interface` - the JSON received by javascript clearly isn't correctly formatted (with respect to the data it is trying to represent) - fix the SENDER of this rubbish JSON

Comment: JSON is valid [here](https://jsonlint.com/?json={%22key%22:%22name%22,%22data%22:%22{\%22name\%22:\%22neil\%22,\%22age\%22:2,\%22address\%22:\%222%20Hill%20St\%22}%22}) check it

Comment: The issue is when creating the data. It looks like `data` is set as JSON, then this is added to an object, which is again "stringified" - therefore x.data is doubly stringified - perhaps you can show HOW this data is being created if you want a **proper** solution

Comment: yes, it's valid JSON, but it's not what is **required** (hence my caveat, *with respect to the data it is trying to represent* )

Comment: if the "sender" of this JSON was written in javascript, it would probably be something like https://jsfiddle.net/ds0wn5du/ - but as the "sender" code is not even in the question, who knows

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your returned JSON contains a string for the data property.

```js
    var response = {"key":"name","data":"{\"name\":\"neil\",\"age\":2,\"address\":\"2 Hill St\"}"};
    //Parse the data 
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(response.data);
    
    console.log(jsonData.name); //neil
    console.log(jsonData.age); //2
    console.log(jsonData.address);//"2 Hill St"
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you have to do JSON.parse(eventData.data) as the data  comes as a string. 
You have to look why that happens. The inner data might be stored in this way, in some cases its valid to store it in db as flat object or it is stringified twice by mistake:

```
var innerdata = JSON.stringify({ name: "neil" });
var eventData = JSON.stringify({ key: "name", data: innerdata });
```

would correspond to your received string.

Correct way to stringify in first place would be:

```
var innerdata = { name: "neil" };
var eventData = JSON.stringify({ key: "name", data: innerdata });
```